# trying to understand the "from" in the "into" closure about a gradle sample

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When learning from the tutorial, I encountered a sample below:

```
task dist(type: Zip) {
    dependsOn spiJar
    from 'src/dist'
    into('libs') {
        from spiJar.archivePath    // what's meaning
        from configurations.runtime // what's meaning
    }
}

artifacts {
   archives dist
}
```

As a newbie to gradle, how to understand this `into(...){ from ...}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the [previews answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33603728/4053652), to, possibly, clarify a little. Due to [dsl reference](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip.html), `Zip` task provide the `into(destPath, configureClosure)` method, which:

> Creates and configures a child CopySpec with a destination directory *inside* the archive for the files.

This means, that it could create an additional directory with the some content in it. In your case, script creates a libs directory within archive and specifies the resources, which should be copied into this directory. This resources could be out of the `src/dist` directory, which will be fully zipped into the archive's root.

Here is a [dsl reference](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html) for CopySpec task, which is configured by the `into` method of the `Zip` task. As you can see, `from` just:

> Specifies source files or directories for a copy.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case:

```
from spiJar.archivePath
```

is probably (since I don't know what exactly `spiJar` is) resolved to the output of `spiJar` task - namely a jar archive - particular file.

When it comes to the second question `configurations` is (simplifying) is a map that matches given name - `runtime` in this case - with a group of dependencies (jar files in this case).

When:

```
from configurations.runtime
```

is used is copies all the dependencies from `runtime` configuration into given destination.

Comment: The sample is "7.3.4. Creating a distribution" from [gradle tutorial](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html#N103DE)

Comment: Ok, so it's all correct. `spiJar` prepares a jar file.